# I need help understanding the use of | in a specific context.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am reading the wikipedia article on Multiple Sequence Alignments and came across some notation I haven't seen yet, specifically $x_i|i = 1,...,r$ in the statement $L > max \{x_i|i = 1,...,r \}$. I was wondering if anyone can shed light onto what that means. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In this case it is just shorthand for $\max\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r\}$. Its meaning varies slightly from context to context, but the bar is usually a stand-in for one of the words "for" or "where" or "such that."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the context of your question, it would mean 'such that'; 'so that'; 'everywhere'. 
Or in other words: 'L is greater than the maximum of the set $x_1, x_2, ...x_r$'

In other contexts, it can mean various other things. I suggest you take a good look at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols